# how to redirect to a subfolder and then rewrite subfolder link to root in htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am sorry if this question is a duplicate but everything I looked for online confused me a lot so I am posting again this question specifying my needs.

Since I want the structure of my website to be clean, I want to separate content from configurations, so I am putting all pages in the `/app` folder (much like a rails app). The structure of the website would be pretty much like this:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── index.php
│   └── products
│       └── index.php
├── configs
└── layouts
```

I found out how to **redirect** the root to the `/app` folder in the `.htaccess` in this way:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ /app [L]
```

When I access the server, apache redirects to the `/app` folder and the url is: `localhost/app`.

I want to **rewrite** urls in order to delete `/app`. For example when I visit the `/products/` folder I don't want the url to look like this: `localhost/app/products/` I want it to look like this: `localhost/products/`

I googled the solution and I've found out that, pretty much like it's done for worpress, you only have to add:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ /app [L]    
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_URI} ^/app/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app/$1 [L]
```

however this just doesn't work and apache return the `500 internal server error`.

I tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ /app [L]  
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_URI} !^/app/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app/$1 [L]
```

and

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ /app [L]  
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_URI} !^/app/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app/$1 [L]
```

and both return `500 internal server error`.

I also tried with:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ /app [L]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/app/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app/$1 [L]
```

but `/app` is still in the url!!

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
 RewriteEngine on

#--Redirect /app/foobar to /foobar--#
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /app/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]
#--Rewrite /foobar to /app/foobar--#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/app
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app/$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```