# how to redirect to a subfolder from root, rewrite subfolder link to look like root, and then add some exceptions in htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I beg you pardon if this is a duplicate question. What I've found on the net didn't satisfy me at all.

As I asked in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35304201/how-to-redirect-to-a-subfolder-and-then-rewrite-subfolder-link-to-root-in-htacce), I successfully rewrote the `/public` folder to the root url. So If I visit `localhost` or `localhost/public` apache redirects me to `/public` and hides public in the url. To sum up, I did it in this way:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

However in this way everything will be redirected to the subfolder `/public`. I need to preserve, or to add some exceptions, to some subdirectories that are not in the `/public` folder.

```
+---assets
+---images
    \---jp-pattern.jpg
+---javascripts
+---stylesheets
+---template
+---public
    \---products
```

I need to preserve *assets, images, javascripts, stylesheets, and template* folders. I need them to be for example `localhost/images` and so on.

I tried with the images folder first in this way:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images [NC]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/?$ [NC]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/images [NC]
```

but none of them worked. The browser always returns me this message:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /public/images/jp-pattern.jpg was not found on this server.
```

This means that I couldn't add the exception.

How can I add those exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this block directly after `RewriteEngine on`:

```bash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(images|javascripts|stylesheets|template)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

This says that if the request begins with either of those directories, don't rewrite. Use of the `L` flag makes that the last rule to be checked.

However, I advise that you actually do an existence check instead. Your HTML would likely be requesting an existing file, and so it would skip the `public` check anyway.

```bash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked!! I have to wait 6 minutes before I can mark as the correct answer though!

Comment: But why does I still have to do this 'include("../template/main.header.php");' in the "public/index.php" file?

Comment: Because you are still including the file relative to `public/index.php` - PHP does not know that you have re-written everything, and so you have to tell it how everything is setup.