# Redirect subfolder to root and hide it in the url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have managed to "rebase" the root from a directory in order to keep public files separated from configs, helpers, and controllers, thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35304201/how-to-redirect-to-a-subfolder-and-then-rewrite-subfolder-link-to-root-in-htacce) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35367895/how-to-redirect-to-a-subfolder-from-root-rewrite-subfolder-link-to-look-like-ro).

However I realized that if a user type `http://domain.com/public` it will not redirect to `http://domain.com` this is harmful for SEO because robots will treat them as two urls thus duplicate.

I need to 301 redirect `/public` to root but as long as I am trying. It doesn't work.

My htaccess looks like the following:

```
# Options
Options +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews -Indexes
DirectorySlash off

# Enable Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Exceptions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(images|javascripts|stylesheets)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# www to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%2://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Make /public like it was root
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [NC,L,QSA]

# Error pages
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /errors/500.php

<files .htaccess="">
  order allow,deny
  deny from all
</files>
```

In this way it will redirect to `http://domain.com//`

How can I fix this issue?

**EDIT**

My website directory structure is:

```
·
|__data
|__controllers
|__helpers
|__partials
|__layouts
|__images
|__javascripts
|__stylesheets
|__public
   |__index.php
   |__subfolder
      |__index.php
```

In root there won't be any index.php pages. So I need to make the `/public` dir as it was my root, in order to keep configs and other directories that users don't have to see separate.

Comment: Is there a .htaccess file inside `public/` as well? Also what exactly isn't working for you?

Comment: @anubhava in `/public` there are only public files that works like urls. Subdirectories of `/public` also works as links. There is no `.htaccess` inside that folder. What it does not work is that if the user type `http://domain.com` and `http://domain.com/public/` the browser will show the same page. The error is that `/public` in this way creates two links, which will generate duplicates for Google. I need to remove `public` in the urls, like it is made with trailing slashes and extensions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your 2 `public/` related rules to this:

```
# add a trailing slash if public/$1 is a directory
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*?[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]

# Make /public like it was root
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+public/(\S*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301,NE]

# internally add public/ to URIs
RewriteRule ^(?!public/).*$ public/$0 [L,NC]
```

Without first trailing slash add rule if you use a URL for sub-directory e.g. `http://domain.com/subfolder` then after 3rd rule adding `public/` in the URI it internally becomes `http://domain.com/public/subfolder` which is a valid directory and Apache's `mod_dir` module adds a trailing slash in the end doing a `301` redirect to `http://domain.com/public/subfolder/` and this will **expose** `public/` part to your clients.

When first trailing slash is there we check if destination is directory and add a trailing slash in original **non-**`/puclic/` URL itself.

Comment: This works just for the first level. As I type `http://domain.com/public` it will redirects to root and that's ok. But if I type `http://domain.com/subfolder` it will display `http://domain.com/public/subfolder/`

Comment: That is because you are missing trailing slash after a directory. What happens when you enter: `http://domain.com/subfolder/` in browser (**don't forget to clear browser cache before every test**)

Comment: Ow, ok I see.. but what if users don't type the trailing slash, which actually happens always?

Comment: I think the problem is that you meant (.*?) rather than (\s*) in that RewriteCond. Or possibly ([^s]*).

Comment: @anubhava Can you please describe what is this exactly -> `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+public/(\s*)\s [NC]` or what you try to accomplish with it and the subsequent rewriterule? Capturing and Redirecting to whitespaces? Thanks in advance.

Comment: With \s* you're matching (and capturing) only whitespace after /public/  That's why it's not working for subdirectories of that public directory - because they don't match that regex.

Comment: Sorry it should have been `\S*` (capital `S`)

Comment: @dcdeiv: Answer updated with additional rule and explanation of trailing slash issue.

Answer (score 1):

There's a number of things here that you need to address, but it appears that the core of it is here:

```
# Make /public like it was root
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

That block is going to generate a loop. It says "if the URL contains public, redirect it to root, but if it does NOT contain public, redirect it to public".

I think what you're trying to do is just:

```
RewriteRule ^public/(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

It's also worth pointing out that your  block at the bottom isn't going to do anything. I suspect that what you meant was:

```
<Files .htaccess>
```

However, for good measure, you might try

```
<FilesMatch ^\.>
```

for all "dot-files".

Comment: You mean that I have to remove the entire block and replace it with that string?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Or, alternately, replace the entire thing with:

Redirect 301 /public/   /

Comment: `That block is going to generate a loop.` No there is no redirect loop, test it out.

Comment: @RichBowen It now lists all indexes of the root directory and it don't display the public dir content. With `-Indexed` it returns 403.

Comment: Sounds like you're missing a DirectoryIndex directive somewhere.

Comment: @RichBowen by adding `DirectoryIndex` it still return 403. In the root there are no index files.

Comment: @dcdeiv Saying you get an error but not mentioning what the error log say is not very helpful to try to help you.

Comment: Yeah, @ezra-s knows what a 403 is. He's one of the regulars helping out on #httpd on Freenode. (Drop by! We'd love to have your help!) However, a 403 may have several different causes (configuration, permissions, selinux, etc) and so having the error log message gives you an immediate answer, rather than guessing and experimenting.

Comment: @RichBowen Sorry but firefox just says 403 forbidden. So no log.

Comment: The log is on the server, typically in /var/log/httpd or the like. However, given your description of your hosting situation, it's likely/probable that you don't have access to that.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, with your edit, it now appears that you're asking the opposite of how I initially interpreted it. It kind of looks to me as though you're introducing an additional layer of complexity in order to protect files that shouldn't be inside the document directory to begin with.

What I would recommend is more from a security perspective than an httpd configuration perspective. If files aren't meant to be public, move them out of the document directory. You'd end up with your regular content, plus images, js and css, in the document directory, and the rest of that stuff outside of it.

Failing that, if you insist on using mod_rewrite to accomplish this, I'd recommend something like the following:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}public%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ /public%{REQUEST_URI} [PT]
```

However, note that this doesn't actually solve the problem, since that "private" content is still there, inside the document directory, waiting for someone to figure out how to get at it.

What I'd recommend is that you take a step back and figure out what problem you're actually trying to solve. If it's the problem of private files being in the document root, the *right* solution is to move them out of that document root, not try to route around them being there.

Comment: I wish I could move them out of the `www` document. But I don't have 20$/month nor almost 0,10$/hour to pay for a VPS. My provider doesn't allow to do it.

Comment: Ok, that's fair. Then what I'd recommend, rather than all of this remapping, is to explicitly forbid access to the sensitive files. You can do this with <FilesMatch> blocks, if the file names are predictable, or with just 'require all denied' in .htaccess files in the "private" directories. This reduces complexity, as well as improving security.

Comment: You mean by adding them to `<FilesMatch ^\.>` as you suggested above?

Comment: For example, if the "private" files were named something.conf, you could protect them with a <FilesMatch \.conf$> block. If, on the other hand, the data/ directory is all private, drop a .htaccess in there containing "Require all denied" and nothing else. In this way, requests for those files result in Forbidden messages, rather than rewrites that someone clever or knowledgeable might find a way around. (I'm not familiar with the framework you're using, so I can't speculate on specifics.)

Comment: Ok! I see! I will certainly do it! I am not using frameworks because here, in Italy, if you want to use them you have to pay for a VPS :(